# How to set charset for German characters?

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am making a multilanguages web site and I have a big problem with German charset.
If i declare "charset=utf-8" German characters are ok but in the rest of my text I get, in some parts, this problem: "�":

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

If I declare "charset=ISO-8859-1" my text is ok but I can't display German charcaters in the right way (e.g. words with "umlaut"):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

How Can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you need to have a look around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618820/will-iso-8859-1-display-german-umlauts-ok-or-do-i-need-to-use-utf-8

Comment: You should consider adding links to the relevant page if possible, so that we can investigate. BTW, I suggest reading [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on character sets and encoding.